# How to solve this error -> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_app.default.auth)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm new to react native and I am using it to create an app sort of like an Instagram clone. I am using React Native in Javascript, Expo cli and firebase. Everything works fine until I try to regiser to the app. This is an app a company has asked me to make as part of my university internship and I've never used react/react-native/firebase etc before now.

Here is the code I have:

Firebase.js

```
import app from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AI*********",
  authDomain: "*********",
  projectId: "*********",
  storageBucket: "*********",
  messagingSenderId: "*********",
  appId: "*********",
  measurementId: "*********"
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
}

export default Firebase;
```

Register.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import app from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

export class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            name: ''
        }
        
        this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)
    }

    onSignUp() {
        const { email, password, name } = this.state;
        app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Name"
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Email"
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Password"
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                />

                <Button 
                    onPress={() => this.onSignUp()}
                    title="Sign Up"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Register
```

Can somebody please help me

Comment: It's hard for anyone to help without knowing what the error is and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your firebase app never initialize as haven't constructed the Firebase object.

As you're using `expo` you can simply follow [this](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#tying-sign-in-providers-with-firebase) guideline.

Add following in you App.js to initialize your firebase app. (You could delete Firebase.js)

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AI*********",
  authDomain: "*********",
  projectId: "*********",
  storageBucket: "*********",
  messagingSenderId: "*********",
  appId: "*********",
  measurementId: "*********"
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//App
export default function App(){
...
}
```

## OR

I think you can import Firebase.js in your App.js and simply create a new instance like

```
import Firebase from './Firebase'

new Firebase();


//App
export default function App(){
...
}
```

Comment: And what would you reccomend I put into the export default function App(){ in here? }

Comment: Don't your project has App.js file? which exports the App component? Here I am just showing where you should put the firebase configuration. You may have class component.


` export default class App extends React.Component {
...
}
`